# Sync problems with Samsung Galaxy I9000

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, sync, google-apps

I'm having the following issues:

1. 'Market' not functioning ('A network error has occurred. Retry, or cancel...')
2. Gmail not functioning ('No connection')
3. Red triangle in top-left of screen = 'Sign-in-error (email address)'

I think these issues are related to the problems I am having with sync-ing Contacts / Calender / Memo with the PC. The process stalls at 25% completion.

The phone also seems to be slower to respond lately.

Any ideas?